# Internal mailing system plugin for Grails

Tags: grails

Is there any internal mailing plugin for Grails? I want the registered users on my system and send mail to each other internally - not using a third party systems such as Gmail or Hotmail . 
Is there something like that? Even if it is developed by java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but this might do the job (assuming you are fine with an internal messaging system instead of real emails):

https://grails.org/plugin/grails-direct-messages

https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-direct-messages

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grails mail plugin but configure it to use your own mail server.

You can use the company exchange server or run your own server using the [Apache James Project](http://james.apache.org/) or a multitude of other mail server application.

Comment: hi , i'm already using the **Mail** plugin for sending outside emails , but what i'm searching for a plugin for internal communication (emails)

Comment: yes but an email needs a server to do that. If you do not want to use an external server you must use an internal server. The linked project is a mail server program that you can run if your company does not have an Microsoft Exchange server or the like.